# How to parse Json and get the required values in Swift/iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift

Here is my Json Data.

```
 {  
   "products":[  

    {  
         "capacity":4,
         "image":"http:\/\/d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net\/car-types\/mono\/mono-uberx.png",
         "display_name":"uberX",
         "product_id":"a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d",
         "description":"The low-cost Uber"
      },
      {  
         "capacity":6,
         "image":"http:\/\/d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net\/car-types\/mono\/mono-uberxl2.png",
         "display_name":"uberXL",
         "product_id":"821415d8-3bd5-4e27-9604-194e4359a449",
         "description":"low-cost rides for large groups"
      },
      {  
         "capacity":4,
         "image":"http:\/\/d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net\/car-types\/mono\/mono-black.png",
         "display_name":"UberBLACK",
         "product_id":"d4abaae7-f4d6-4152-91cc-77523e8165a4",
         "description":"The original Uber"
      },
      {  
         "capacity":6,
         "image":"http:\/\/d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net\/car-types\/mono\/mono-suv.png",
         "display_name":"UberSUV",
         "product_id":"8920cb5e-51a4-4fa4-acdf-dd86c5e18ae0",
         "description":"Room for everyone"
      },
      {  
         "capacity":4,
         "image":"http:\/\/d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net\/car-types\/mono\/mono-taxi.png",
         "display_name":"uberTAXI",
         "product_id":"3ab64887-4842-4c8e-9780-ccecd3a0391d",
         "description":"Taxi without the hassle"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want  all values represented by keys `i.e capacity, image, display_name,product_id, description` and save in lists given bellow

```
    var  array_capacity = Array<Int>();
    var  array_image = Array<String>();
    var  array_display_name = Array<String>();
    var  array_product_id = Array<String>();
    var  array_description = Array<String>();
```

but it crashed. I think this is because of some casting issue.

Here is my parsing code.

```
var responseDict: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData,options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error:nil) as NSDictionary

        if(!(responseDict==nil)){

             var products: NSArray = responseDict["products"] as NSArray

                for item in products { // loop through data items
                    let obj = item as NSDictionary
                    for (key, value) in obj {


                       // print(key as String);

                        array_product_id.append(value as String);
                        array_display_name.append(value as String);
                        array_image.append(value as String);
                        array_description.append(value as String);
                        array_capacity.append(value as Int);

                }

            }


        }
```

Log

```
    libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional:
0x109c55f30:  pushq  %rbp
0x109c55f31:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x109c55f34:  pushq  %rbx
0x109c55f35:  pushq  %rax
0x109c55f36:  movq   %rsi, %rcx
0x109c55f39:  movq   %rdi, %rbx
0x109c55f3c:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x109c55f3e:  testq  %rbx, %rbx
0x109c55f41:  je     0x109c55f5d               ; swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 45
0x109c55f43:  movq   0x7858e(%rip), %rsi       ; "isKindOfClass:"
0x109c55f4a:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x109c55f4d:  movq   %rcx, %rdx
0x109c55f50:  callq  *0x63112(%rip)            ; (void *)0x000000010be04000: objc_msgSend
0x109c55f56:  testb  %al, %al
0x109c55f58:  movq   %rbx, %rax
0x109c55f5b:  je     0x109c55f64               ; swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 52
0x109c55f5d:  addq   $0x8, %rsp
0x109c55f61:  popq   %rbx
0x109c55f62:  popq   %rbp
0x109c55f63:  retq   
0x109c55f64:  leaq   0xecc7(%rip), %rax        ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
0x109c55f6b:  movq   %rax, 0x7fbe6(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x109c55f72:  int3   
0x109c55f73:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

Comment: Can you share the crash log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are iterating over NSDictionary in swift way. The NSDictionary does not seem to be compliant to swift sequence so your iteration over NSDictionary using key value crashes. Use the allKeys methods for NSDictionary and pull the values regularly as you would do for Objective C like so,

```
if  let jsonData = jsonString?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false){

  if let jsonObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as? [String: AnyObject]{

    if let products: AnyObject = jsonObject["products"]{

      for aProduct in products as NSArray{

        for aKey in (aProduct as NSDictionary).allKeys{

          println(aKey)

        }

      }

    }
  }

}
```

One thing that you are doing wrong is appending the values from the dictionary to and you are using dynamic cast to cast it to string or Int. That is not the way to do and that crashes your code again, you optional to check if it can be casted to the type using if let and then append the value to your array.

Comment: thanks for your time. how can I check that it can be casted ? how to use if let. I m new to swift. please help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the error occured in this part:

```
array_product_id.append(value as String);
array_display_name.append(value as String);
array_image.append(value as String);
array_description.append(value as String);
```

You can check if a value can be cast-ed to a specific object like this:

```
if let specificObject = dictionary["key"] as? String
{
    // specificObject has a value of string
} 
else
{
    // dictionary["key"] can't be cast-ed to string
}
```

The above example check if the value of `dictionary["key"]` can be cast-ed to `String`.

**UPDATE:** Change these lines. You are iterating through dictionary, content of `value` can be string and casted to Int or vise versa causing the error.

```
for (key, value) in obj {

   array_product_id.append(value as String);
   array_display_name.append(value as String);
   array_image.append(value as String);
   array_description.append(value as String);
   array_capacity.append(value as Int);

}
```

Instead:

```
 // Remove the for-loop

 array_product_id.append(obj["your_key_here"] as String);
 array_display_name.append(obj["your_key_here"] as String);
 array_image.append(obj["your_key_here"] as String);
 .
 .
 .
```

Comment: Thanks now this worked. but I have to use the loop. like this 
if let products: AnyObject = responseDict["products"]{
                
                for aProduct in products as NSArray{

                        array_capacity.append(aProduct["capacity"] as Int);
                        array_image.append(aProduct["image"] as String);
                        array_display_name.append(aProduct["display_name"] as String);
                        array_product_id.append(aProduct["product_id"] as String);
                }

Answer (score 0):

For me the casting error was because the the values were in integer:

```
"capacity":4,
```

making all the values as string:

```
"capacity":"4",
```

removes the casting error :

```
     for item in products { // loop through data items
                let obj = item as NSDictionary
                for (key, value) in obj {
                println("\"\(key as String)\" : \"\(value as String)\"")
        }

      }
```

Unless you need the value to be in Int.
These what worked for me.